# Learn Angular with Typescript in Visual studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I am new to Angular. I am trying to create a Angular application using visual studio 2015. I have installed all the requirements and configurations needed to work with Angular in VS2015 as mentioned [here](http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/).

I have learnt the basics in Angular. Now I need continue with Angular sample projects to learn deeply.

In my first sample project, I have three .ts(transcript) files,
Main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './boot';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

boot.ts

```
///<reference path="./../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts"/>
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app';

@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule],
declarations: [AppComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `    
<h2>My favorite skill is: {{myskills}}</h2>
<p>Skill:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let skl of skills">
    {{ skl }}
  </li>
</ul>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'ASP.NET MVC 5 with Angular 2';
skills = ['MVC 5', 'Angular 2', 'TypeScript', 'Visual Studio 2015'];
myskills = this.skills[1];
}
```

I am getting confused whether to create the component first in app.ts or to create module in boot.ts etc.

1.) Do I need to learn typescript before working on Angular?
2.) Prefer me links where I can get sample projects to learn these basics.
3.) Any kind of books to learn from scratch.

Comment: *Do I need to learn typescript before working on Angular?* Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample application which explains step by step details to create angular (Angular v4) applications with Asp.net MVC framework. Below is the link. I am working on modular application as well which I will be updating soon. Hope this helps you.

http://hive.rinoy.in/angular4-and-asp-net-mvc-hybrid-application/

Comment: Thank you so much. It will be very useful if you update me once you have updated with your modular application.